# Why are my WordPress blog posts not showing?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm working on a custom WP theme with a blog page. The Blog page is showing the posts but when you click on each post, it takes you to an empty page.

I've set: Settings > Post Page > Blog

Basically, blog page displays all content but BLOG POST page is blank. Here's my `index.php`.

```
<div class="header-img-container container-fluid">
    <img 
    class="header-img" 
    role="banner" 
    src="http://cc.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/blog-page.jpg"  
    >
    <hr class="horizontal-line">

</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col">

                <div class="vertical-center">
                    <form action="http://cc.fullslate.com/">
                        <button class="appointment-button btn button">Schedule</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <p class="page-body-title">Blog</p>
                <div id="primary" class="content-area">
                    <main id="main" class="site-main">

                    <?php
                    if ( have_posts() ) {

                        // Load posts loop.
                        while ( have_posts() ) {
                            the_post();
                            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content/content' );
                        }

                        // Previous/next page navigation.
                        //cc_the_posts_navigation();

                    } else {

                        // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
                        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content/content', 'none' );

                    }
                    ?>

                    </main><!-- .site-main -->
                </div><!-- .content-area -->
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you've the single.php file in your theme structure? i believe it's missing.

Comment: yeah, maybe that is what I'm missing. I just need to figure out what I should have in there now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit the view of a single post, you need to use the single.php
Find out more about template hierarchy in wordpress:
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Here is what it should look like:
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/post-template-files/

You can adjust this single.php to your needs, it will work as it is because of the post loop in it.